# What are some MERN projects that will grow me from junior dev to senior

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I just want some project ideas that will help me get a more better job / senior profile role in web dev using MERN stack

I have built some projects in Front end using React, Redux and Tailwind CSS like Youtube, Netflix and Food ordering app. But I had to rely on API which was already built. Now I am learning backend and want to make some awesome projects in MERN